# Separable-Prefix verbs positions in an answer

Tags: separable-verb, question

When answering

> Wann fangen Ihre Vorlesungen jeden Tag an?

Should I still put the *an* at the end of my answer like the following

> Meine Vorlesungen fangen meistens um zehn Uhr jeden Tag an.

Is that correct?

Comment: Meistens oder jeden Tag?

Comment: @userunknown, he meint jeden Tag is fix but only the time(hour) of lessons has irregularity otherweise yes of course at the weekend there is no lecture,this would be another detail when we digg his sentence

Comment: @user1474062: »Jeden Tag« means »every single day, without an exception«. »Meistens« means »most times, but not always.« So you can't use a term that mean »not always« together with a term that means »always« to describe the same situation. Either it is always (»jeden Tag«) or not (»meistens«). It can't be both at the same time.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast, Er hat jeden Tag Vorlesungen, die Vorlesungen fangen meistens um zehn Uhr an. That's what he tries to convey.

Comment: @user1474062: Wenn das so ist, dann fangen die Vorlesungen meistens um zehn Uhr an. Dann gibt es aber ab und zu auch Tage, an denen sie um 11 oder um 9, also nicht um 10 Uhr anfangen. Und wenn das so ist, dann ist die Aussage »sie fangen jeden Tag um 10 Uhr an« falsch. Aber der Satz »Meine Vorlesungen fangen meistens um zehn Uhr jeden Tag an.« sagt aus: »Die Vorlesungen fangen jeden Tag um 10 an, und sie fangen nicht jeden Tag um 10 an.« So etwas nennt man in der Aussagenlogik eine »Kontradiktion« (eine Aussage, die unter allen Interpretationen immer falsch ist).

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast yes you are right the sentence could be maybe split into two parts with relative clause. Do you mean there is an ambiguity(doppeldeutigkeit) there? Maybe that because of he couldn't convey the beginning time of lectures and the days he has lectures to visit.In my opinion a relative clause is missing.

Comment: @user1474062: Der Satz ist nicht doppeldeutig, sondern falsch. Er ist so sinnvoll wie »Ich kaufe meistens immer Milch.« Entweder *meistens* oder *immer*. Aber beides auf dasselbe Objekt bezogen ist falsch. Erlaubt wäre »Ich kaufe *immer in diesem Geschäft* ein, und kaufe *meistens Milch*.« Denn dann beziehen sich *immer* und *meistens* auf verschiedene Aktivitäten. Aber im Satz aus dem Frageposting beziehen sich sowohl *meistens* als auch *jeden Tag* auf dasselbe Ereignis (nämlich auf den Beginn der Vorlesungen). Und dadurch widersprechen sie einander.

Answer (score 3):

I had separable prefixes for homework last week and yes, we put the *an* at the end of the sentences in a response. If it follows a subordinating conjunction however, it would not be separated.

Answer (score 1):

An Answer is just a normal sentence. There is no difference between answers and other messages. There is nothing special at answers. So all rules, that work for sentences that are not questions work for answers too.

Questions are different, they have a different word order (and a question mark at the end).